# NSURLConnection leakage

Tags: iphone, sdk, nsurlconnection

I'm following the official Apple sample

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

While examining my code with Instruments I found a leak, caused by the non released NSURLRequest. I've now included a `[request release]` shortly after

```
NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

and it seems to work. Am I right?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The request is autoreleased which means that the autorelease pool should take care of releasing it. If you are using that within a Cocoa application you should have an autorelease pool setup automatically that will handle the freeing of autoreleased objects.

If you are working on a non-cocoa app you will have to set that up yourself and make sure to release/drain the pool in order to free your objects.

Generally you only need to release objects created with `alloc`, `copy`, `mutableCopy` or if you sent it `retain`. That means you will have to release the connection object that you created with `[[NSURLConnection alloc] init...` or it will cause a leak.

Here is the link to a document about [Autorelease Pools](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see. For some reasons I've mixed the "official" sample with my own realization :) In my code I was doing this:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url];
```

and this has of course to be released. The sample I mentioned above behaves different. Seemed to be rather late last night.

However, many thanks for your answer.

One thing drives me crazy: I don't get an email notification, if someone answers to my questions, although I've set the marker...

Regards